# How to configure JAAS at Jboss application server

Tags: jboss, jaas

I am migrating J2EE application from Glassfish 4 to Jboss AS 7. The application uses JAAS security in GF4. Since, I am completely new to Jboss, can anyone provide pointers on how to configure JAAS security in JBOSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got this pointer to implement JAAS in Jboss http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/09/18/configure-jaas-jboss-7-1-mysql/